# How does 何で usage exactly work with 言う?

Tags: grammar

So I know that 何で can be used to ask 'why' or to ask "with what" in a negatively structured sentence. Like, お姉ちゃんは何で学校に行きますか.

But when I wanted to learn how to say, "idk what to say" a Japanese person suggested the same usage to me, like 何で言えばいいか分からない so i'm curious now why isn't it 何を?

I'm a newbie learner sorry if this looks funny.

Comment: That person must have said 何て, which is different from 何で.

Comment: ah okay can you explain てusage in there as well? what is て used for?

Comment: 何**て**言えばいいか means the same as 何**と**言えばいいか. i.e. it has a quoting function here.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers pointed out, it was

> 何て言えばいいか分からない

何て means "indefinite way" or "how" and it's the adverb form of 何.

It literally means: "If I say (it) in an indefinite way, I wouldn't understand if it's good". -> "I don't know how to say it"

Answer (score 0):

It was **何て**言うの. 何て when used in this context (question form) simply means "what".

And I'll add this, when you say **何を**言えばいいか分からない it feels like you are describing somebody else who's at a loss for words, "He doesn't know what to say", not "Idk what to say". I don't have a dictionary backing me up, but it just feels this way after reading a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> How does 何で usage exactly work with 言う?

Why not? But first you have to see that 何で can mean two different things: `why` (in which case it's read as 何{なん}で) or `by what` (in which case it's read as 何{なに}で)

So for your two example sentences, they're both correct, but it's just that in the first, the 何で means `by what`

> Q: お姉ちゃんは何{なに}で学校に行きますか
> A: 自転車で学校に行きます

> Q: By what means does the sister go to school?
> A: By bike

In the second sentence, the 何で means `why`, and is analogous to なぜ or どうして

> 何{なん}で言えばいいか分からない
> I don't understand why is it good if I can say it

In short, 何{なに}で and 何{なん}で are different words that mean different thing.